# Issue with PluralizationServices (c#)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, pluralize

I was just playing with System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.

Have you experienced issues with this function?

If I have a string var with value "ducks" and run

```
string noun = "ducks";

noun = System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Singularize(noun);
```

I still get the plural.

Yet if I do the same with a literal string it works as expected.

```
string noun = string.Empty;

noun = System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture).Singularize("ducks");
```

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. How do you test your code?

Comment: I can reproduce it with the above lines of code.  I just threw the above in a little console app to try it out.